# Property 'FoodCourtService' does not exist on type 'FoodcourtStallsComponent'

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { FoodCourtService } from '../../shared/service/food-court.service';
import { Foodstalls } from "../../shared/model/foodstalls.model";

@Component({
       selector: 'app-foodcourt-stalls',
       templateUrl: './foodcourt-stalls.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./foodcourt-stalls.component.css']
})
export class FoodcourtStallsComponent implements OnInit {

      foodstallArr : Foodstalls [] = [];

      constructor
          (public router: Router,
           public route: ActivatedRoute,
           public FoodCourtStallService : FoodCourtService) {
     }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.foodstallArr = this.FoodCourtService.getFoodCourts();
      }
  }
```

It says:

> 'FoodCourtService' doesnt exist even though it does when i imported it
>   here     import { FoodCourtService } from
>   '../../shared/service/food-court.service';

Comment: You've called the paramter `FoodCourtStallService` not `FoodCourtService`, so you need `this.FoodCourtStallService` (although it is of type `FoodCourtService`)

Answer (score 0):

You should call the injected service name , without the original service name, change it as follows.

```
 ngOnInit() {
          this.foodstallArr = this.FoodCourtStallService.getFoodCourts();
   }
```